# Difference of two pattern rules and integration on makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm learning makefile and I'm little bit confused about the use of pattern rule and how to use it:

I have two questions:

1. difference form of pattern rules

In some examples I saw this form:

```
.c.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Other times I saw this:

```
%.o: %.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Is this the same form or there are many differences?

1. How to integrate the pattern rule in my makefile

I have a makefile like this:

```
.PHONY: all brsserver brsclient clean
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -g -lpthread

# source files for server
SOURCES_SERV = brsserver.c func_client_serv.c comsock.c bris.c users.c aux_func.c Stack.c

# source files for client
SOURCES_CLI = brsclient.c func_client_serv.c comsock.c bris.c users.c aux_func.c Stack.c

# object file for server
OBJECTS_SERV = $(SOURCES_SERV:.c = .o)

# object file for client
OBJECTS_CLI = $(SOURCES_SERV:.c = .o)

# executable file server
SERV_EXE = brsserver

# executable file client
CLI_EXE = brsclient
```

I did this:

```
$(SERV_EXE): $(OBJECTS_SERV)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ newDeck.o
$(CLI_EXE): $(OBJECTS_CLI)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

But I want to use the pattern rule to do `make brsserver` and `make brsclient` from command.
it's enough do this?

`%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@`

As you can see, I have to complie only the `brsserver` including a module called `newDeck.o`.

Comment: I didn't understand your last question.  Why doesn't `make brsserver` or `make brsclient` work right now, as you have things?  Also I didn't understand what you mean by `newDeck.o`; there is nothing like this mentioned in your example.

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't work. I just want use pattern rule.
NewDeck is a module that I used for compile server, as u can see.

Comment: If you want to have a new source file built and linked into the server, you should add it to the `SOURCES_SRV` variable, not into the linker rule.  That's why you have a variable.  Add `newDeck.c` to the end of `SOURCES_SRV = ...` and you'll be done.

Comment: Oh, you should not add `-lpthread` to `CFLAGS`.  `CFLAGS` takes compiler flags; any flag starting with `-l` is a linker flag telling it where to find a library.  The `-l` flags go into the `LDLIBS` variable, typically.  But just adding `-lpthread` to the link line is not good enough if you're really using threads.  You should add the `-pthread` (note NOT `-lpthread`!) to `CFLAGS`, then you don't need to use `-lpthread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.c.o` form is a *suffix rule*.  This form is defined in the POSIX standard for the `make` program.

The `%.o : %.c` is a *pattern rule*.  This is a GNU make feature, not part of the POSIX standard (I think there may be a few other make implementations that have something similar).

In this case, they are equivalent.  However pattern rules in general are much more flexible than suffix rules; for example you can't represent a pattern rule like this:

```
foo%.o : bar%.c
```

as a suffix rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explain. So, definetly in which way I have to use that pattern rule ? In addition on or instead of my compilation?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question.